# Credentials parameter with get-counter

Tags: powershell

```
Is there any way to use Credentials parameter with get-counter?
```

I tried the below code, but it didn't work. I am using here a local user account which has admin access on Target server.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername XXXX -ScriptBlock {(get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 | select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average} -Credential XXXX\YYYY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Documentation says [Nope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx)

Judging by your code you are trying to supply username and password to the credentials parameter as a string but that is not how it works. You have to create a credential object like so:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “PlainTextPassword” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“username”, $secpasswd)
```

After that you can call `Invoke-Command` and supply `$mycreds` as credentials:

```
Invoke-Command -Computername XXXX -ScriptBlock {(get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 | select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average} -Credential $mycreds
```

If you are supplying the credentials correctly and it still does not work you could try to use `Invoke-Command` inside your Scriptblock again and supply the credentials there.

You can pass the credential object as a parameter to the Scriptblock with the `-Argumentlist` parameter and access it inside the Scriptblock by using `$args[0]` or making a parameter declaration inside of the Scriptblock and accessing it by the declared name.

Comment: [XXXX] Connecting to remote server XXXX failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.

Comment: -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

Comment: -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (XXXX:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: @SumanGhosh Ok did you make Sure the credentials work? Create the same object on your target Server locally and try to invoke a command and See if it Works. Do you include the target computername as a Domain in the credentials like "pcname\user"? If not try that. Otherwise you could also add the Computer running the Script to the trusted hosts file on the target machine

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Credential is ok. I have verified it. I tried with pcname\user. enabled psremoting on target server. but no luck.
SO I just left it.
trying to find another way.